# How to access rootscope in component view

Tags: html, angularjs, view, scope, rootscope

I have angular controller dashboard and set the root scope value in dashboard and access that root scope value in component inside the dashboard template using scope..but i don't know whether this is correct or not..and am not able to get that value

```
function DashBoardController($http, $window, $rootScope, apiurl, $scope, $location,$interval) {
        var ctrl = this;    
        ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            getUser();
        };    
        function getUser(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: apiurl + '/getUser',
            }).success(function (data, status) {
                if (data.status == true) {
                    $rootScope.user  = data.result; 
                    $rootScope.test = "TEST";

                }  
            });
        }  

function Controller1($rootScope,$scope, $timeout,$http, apiurl,$interval) {
        var ctrl = this;    
         $scope.value = $rootScope.test;
   alert($scope.value);
       $scope.value1 = $rootScope.user;
   console.log($scope.value1);
}
    app.module('app').component('component1', {
        templateUrl: '../resources/views/component/component1.html',
        controller: Controller1
    });
})(window.angular);
```

am getting undefined

Comment: Please initialize $rootScope.test = "TEST" , when DashBoardController load at first time.

Comment: I need $rootscope.user value from getUser() function @JigarPrajapati

Comment: Yes but first of all at that time your main controller will load, you should initialize it, then after whenever your getUser() function will call, it will overwrite it's value. But main thing is you need to initialize it.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati..after initialize also am getting undefined

Comment: Can you please provide working code snippet here? so that i can get better idea, and provide you a effective solution.

Comment: Because i have no idea, when you are calling Controller1 controller.

Comment: getUser() is defined in your DashBoardController, and you tell me, as you are never calling this controller at any moment, so how can root scope will get initialize?

Comment: Is Controller1 is called after DashBoardController?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN ...controller1 is component bind with dashboard page

Comment: @JigarPrajapati.. i want to store the $rootScope.user  = data.result;  after the getUser function call ...and same time need to access that in my controller1. console.log($rootScope) i can able to see the value,but accessing its undefined

Comment: Then you need utilize a then method of angular, this will allow you to wait until your function will return response and then you can initialize it.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati ..how to initialize  that method...i'm not aware of that about angular

Comment: let me to make one code snippet for you by posting an answer.

Comment: @JigarPrajapati.,. I don't know how to give code snippet

Answer (score 28):

From template you can access rootscope variables via `$root.varName`

Comment: Thank you.  That's what *I* needed to do, at least.